# Android studio build failed unresolved reference error

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio, android-studio-girafee

Unable to build android studio project when we try to add new layouts in xmls. Even though the reference is available through view binding android studio throws Unresolved reference error

- I have tried clearing the cache
- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Restarting android studio